# Compact camera with good zoom range and wide angle

Tags: equipment-recommendation, zoom

I use to have Ricoh Caplio R7, I loved it’s zoon range and wide angle lens.

However its lens kept sticking that will have a few weeks to get fixed under the warranty each time.

Also it’s zoom control is too small for my wife to use.  My wife could not even pick up the camera without pressing the “shoot” button, as its body is a bit too thin.  However we want a camera that will fit in a normal pocket.  (My wife can use a normal sized compact camera without a problem)

What options should I consider for its replacement?

Comment: Did you try the feature search at dpreview? That could help you do identify a few candidates: http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/compare.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could make good use of a "travel zoom" camera and, as Frederick mentioned, dpreview.com have lots of details about them. In particular, a recent [travel zoom group test](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/Q210grouptravelzoom/) shows some of the best current contenders.

From those options, I would personally recommend the [Panasonic ZS5](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/Q210grouptravelzoom/page9.asp) for it's 25-300mm zoom and image/camera quality. But since you have a specific need of separate zoom controls, you may want to consider the [Olympus µ-9010](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/Q210grouptravelzoom/page8.asp) then (in the U.S. you may need to settle for the [9000](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/q209grouplongzoom/page3.asp) model, which features a harder to use zoom control).

Comment: The problem with the Panasonic is "12x zoom is controlled using a toggle switch around the shutter release" that will be as hard for my wife to use as the zoom control on the Ricoh Caplio.

Comment: Right, for that you may want to check the Olympus µ-9010 (or 9000 if you live in the U.S.), see the link above.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to want to go to micro 4/3, I strongly recommend Canon S90. Its zoom range is not as long as the Ricoh but it's reliable and easy to use. It has fast lens, excellent high ISO, and large screens. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a compact, I can recommend the Nikon Coolpix S8000. It has a very nice lens which starts wide and has a 10x zoom factor. The camera itself is quite pocketable, and feels very sturdy.

Comment: +1 Fantastic camera.  Since I got mine I carry it as backup to my macro prime and long telephoto.

Comment: @Matthew Indeed, I purchased the S8000 to be a supplement to my D50, which I don't always have with me.

Answer (score 0):

The Caplio line still exists and has seen a number of new models since the R7. As well as the usual image quality advances they have also fixed up the lens sticking problems, the camera has gotten slightly heftier, the layout of the controls has been improved and the zoom is slightly longer. Aside from that it's still essentially the same device, so you wouldn't have to relearn the UI, which can be a significant advantage.

The current models are the CX-1 through CX-3.

Comment: given I could not get I refund due to the lens sticking problem, I don't think I will every trust a Caplio again.

Comment: Also the Caplio still seems to have the very hard to use zoom slider rathern then two easy to use button like most cameras